# How can I use authentication in Mongo sink?

Tags: spring-xd

http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.RC1/reference/html/#mongo

The options for mongo sink does not specify any arguments for passing user/password.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback!

It isn't supported now: https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2674.

To overcome it you should modify `/modules/sink/mongodb/config/mongodb.xml` with `<context-property:placeholder>` and add appropriate keys for the `<mongo:db-factory >`.

Comment: on the same note, does the mongo connection support SSL?